# what does the .(dot) do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

im a newbie trying to understand a this huge word that JavaScript is and my question is: 
what does the . dot do?

ex:

blabla . (dot) forEach
blabla . (dot) src = blabla .(dot)width

how do you describe the functionality of the dot?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It let's you access something that is part of the object on the left.

For example let's go with this object:

`var myObject = { Name: "Object#1", Description: "An object to use as an example" };`

You now have an object you can pass around. For example, you can log it to the console:

`console.log(myObject);`

Basically you take the `console` (which you can access from anywhere), access its function called `log`, and execute that function using (), telling it to do something using the parameter `myObject`. In this case, it will write information about your object in the console.

Now, maybe you just want the Name of the object logged to console. You can pass only the name to the function by calling it like this:

`console.log(myObject.Name)`

which means "use myObject, take its property called "Name", pass its value to the function called `log` from the console and execute that". SO now it will write "Object#1" to the console.